# MsSql JDBC driver 7.2 for Sql Server 2008?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix, Microsoft has listed *Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server Support Matrix* which says that driver version 7.2 is not compatible with SQL Server 2008.

I am confused as in what does it mean? Microsoft has stopped supporting SQL Server 2008 with driver version 7.2 or it's not compatible at all?

I ran a test and I could fetch data from a SQL Server 2008 database using driver version 7.2.

Should I use driver version 7.2 in my application to connect to Sql Server 2008 or not?

Comment: The document says that 7.2 isn't compatible with 2008, so that's what it means. JDBC *may* work for what you're using it for against SQL Server 2008 but that doesn't mean it will always work, or not produce unexpected results. Effectively Microsoft are not guaranteeing things will work correctly if you use 7.2, however, they do with version 6.2. On the other hand, SQL Server 2008 (R2) has less than 2 months left of support now, so you should really be looking at upgrade paths; and every other (supported) version of SQL Server supports JDBC 7.2.

Comment: @Larnu I knew this somewhere in my mind...but didn't want to accept it as it will block some decisions for my application. Anyway..thanks for the explanation...we have to face the truth. I think I will use 7.2 and will rely on automation tests for Sql Server 2008.

Comment: personally, like I said above, i'd suggest upgrading your SQL Server instance, @S.K. . Like i said, you have less than 2 months left of support. If your a business affected by GDPR, then you'll also be non-compliant with their regulations, which could result in (significant) fines in the event that you get any attention. Plus the fact that any security faults won't be patched, meaning that you won't be secure any more. There are a lot of implications of using unsupported software, and these are but a couple.

Comment: @Larnu Oh...I forgot to mention...Updating sql server instances is not in my hands. Those are basically at the customer's site. My application should basically connect to any sql server instance it is configured with.

Comment: Well I *suppose* you can tell them (or at least in 2 months) that as they're using an **unsupported** version of SQL Server it's not your fault if JDBC doesn't work. Software vendors can't be expected to provide non-bespoke solutions for unsupported software. I'd give them a gentle reminder or note of that. if they do then start having problems, it'll push them towards using a version of SQL Server that 7.2 does support, and then this becomes a non-issue. :)

Comment: That makes sense...will keep that in mind. Thanks for the conversation!